# Upload bandwidth limitation

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-extensions, bandwidth, upload

**Are there any options how do I limit the upload bandwidth used to say 25% or 50% of the full upload bandwidth?** While uploading files:

- in the web-browser,
- in the email client like outlook,
- FTP clients etc.

The upload limitation could work either:

- as a plugin in the web-browser (any plugin for firefox?) for browser uploads,
- as a system tool.

BitTorrent can do it well (but unfortunatelly not as percent), the best way it is implemented is in WinSCP.

Comment: I think you could use some kind of proxy server that can limit network bandwith, but not for concrete app or kind of apps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Qos (Quality of Service) in your router to cut down your upload speeds to the speed you choose.

[A Beginner’s Guide to Using QoS (Quality of Service) on Your Router](http://www.howtogeek.com/75660/the-beginners-guide-to-qos-on-your-router/)

Comment: Thanks, but my question was about client side solution - how to voluntarily throttle down the data I send.